# Recalling sheet names for a while loop

Tags: python, export-to-excel, xlrd, worksheet

I have imported xlrd etc. The main part of my code is then as follows:

```
for serie_diam in range(0,9):
namesheet = "Diamètre " + str(serie_diam)
#select(namesheet)
numLine = sh.row_values(3)
OK = 1
while OK == 1:
    d = sh1(numLine, 1)
    D = sh1(numLine, 2)
    rs = sh1(numLine, 7)
    for i in range(4):
        BB = sh1(numLine, 2 + i)
        if BB != 0:
            print repr(d).rjust(2), repr(D).rjust(3), repr(B).rjust(4), repr(rs).rjust(5)
```

I have 7 sheets in my xls file overall and I would like to know how I can loop through these in the same while loop as OK == 1 where for the moment I have written just 'sh1'.

I'm sorry if this question is too easy!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('xlrd_test.xls')

for sheet in book.sheets():
    print sheet.row(0) # do stuff here - I'm printing the first line as example

# or if you need the sheet index for some purpose:
for shidx in xrange(0, book.nsheets):
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(shidx)
    # would print 'Page N, first line: ....'
    print 'Page %d, first line: %s' % (shidx, sheet.row(0))
```